# Cracked Tile in New Construction Home - Foundation issues?

Tags: foundation, ceramic-tile, damage, cracks

I've recently moved into a new home built in June 2019. Some hairline cracks developed in some of my tiles, but I didn't worry about it too much because they were barely noticeable and the builder is not honoring his warranty. They wouldn't come out to replace their faulty AFCI breaker less than a month into my ownership.

Today, I went into my guest bathroom and noticed that the tile has cracked all the way across the entire floor. To make matters worse, these cracks are large enough that I can feel the edges, and small pieces chipped off while I ran my finger along them. No one uses this bathroom regularly and nothing has fallen on the floor.

Someone has mentioned to me that I might have a serious foundation issue. I'm scared. This is my first home, and I haven't owned it for a year. I have written the builder with images and expressed my concerns and requested that this be address as part of my 1 year warranty but I fully expect to be given grief about it. I can't afford to do major flooring repairs on a house that's brand new.

The images are attached. Can anyone offer any insight?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIqLE.jpg

Thanks,

Dustin

Comment: What are the tiles installed on...wood flooring or concrete slab?

Answer (score 3):

Your slab has cracked and that it why your tiles are cracking. This is not good and you need to document everything with pictures and get back with the builder to fix this. Check with your Better Business Bureau (or whoever you have) to see about attorneys who could help if it should come to that. Send copies of the pictures and descriptions of the damage to the builder via certified mail. Get this ball rolling while your still under warranty. Good luck.

Comment: Agreed. Note @JACK specified certified mail. You want a signature that verifies that the builder was notified of the issue within warranty. Also cc the BBB.

Answer (score 1):

The substrate may or may not be concrete. In any case, you don't need to know, as this is an item that the builder needs to fix under warranty.

If they won't do it, consult a lawyer, NOW. The contractor wants you to let it go, they are literally banking on it.

You shouldn't let it go, you paid for it to be correct